Continuity Equation for Steady State Flow vs Incompressible flow
Good day guys,
I have been reading on the continuity equations on the slides of my fluid dynamics course.
I was introduced to the following definitions:

Steady state flow: $\forall f \in \text{Flow properties} \mid \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=0 $.


Unsteady state flow: $\exists f \in \text{Flow properties} \mid \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\neq 0 $.


Compressible flow: $\rho = f(x,y,z)$.


Incompressible flow: $\rho = \text{constant in space}$.

Now I am reading on the continuity equation section, in its most general form (for a CV with no sink nor source), we have
$$ \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} - \nabla (\rho \cdot \vec{v}) = 0 $$
Then, the slides say that for an incompressible fluid:
$$\nabla \cdot \vec{v} = 0 $$
However, I am confused as to why the time-dependent term vanished? Would that not imply we also assumed the flow is steady? Using the definitions on my notes and stating from the general form of the continuity equation.

If flow is steady, then: $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}=0$.

Therefore,
$$\nabla (\rho \cdot \vec{v}) = 0 $$

If incompressible, then: $\rho = \text{constant in space}$.

Therefore,
$$\rho(\nabla \cdot \vec{v}) = 0 \rightarrow \nabla \cdot \vec{v} = 0 $$
I want to make sure my understanding of all these terms is correct, so it all make sense when I go from the general form to the one that appears to be the a form for (steady state + incompressible flow). Could it be my lectures slides did not define properly the conditions for steady flow and incompressibility?

If this is what you got from the lectures, things got messed up somewhere in the learning process (slides, lecturer, you?). May I ask what institute are you enrolled in?

I think the lecturer got some things wrong, they tend to not rigorous with their math (it is an engineering course). Also, there will probably a lot of errors on my part as I am trying to be formal with my understanding as I go through the non-rigorous notes.

Please let me know if there is anything that needs to be fixed to improve the question. Thank you all.

Before answering your question, I'd suggest to review basics of differential calculus and operators, since your use of notation looks weak.
Now, let's focus on your question, splitting the answer in some paragraph.
Continuity equation. Continuity equation reads, in conservative form,
$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot \left( \rho \mathbf{u} \right) = 0 \ ,$$
or in convective form
$$0 = \dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla \rho + \rho \nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} \qquad \rightarrow \qquad \dfrac{D \rho}{D t} + \rho \nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} = 0$$
being $\rho(\mathbf{r}, t)$, and $\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{r},t)$ the density field and the velocity field respectively, and $\frac{D}{Dt}$ the material derivative, representing the operator providing the time derivative of a quantity (the quantity the operator is applied to) as seen by material particles (i.e. points moving with the continuum).
Incompressibility constraint. Incompressibility constraint doesn't imply constant density, but it implies that the density "of each material particle" doesn't change, i.e. mathematically,
$$\frac{D \rho}{D t} = 0 \ ,$$
or equivalently (you can realize this immediately using the convective form of the mass equation) that the velocity field is divergence-free,
$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} = 0 \ .$$
Steady flow. Since the Eulerian approach is the most common approach in fluid dynamics, steady conditions are defined as these conditions where
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial t} \equiv 0 \ ,$$
i.e. the partial time derivative (keeping fixed the space coordinate) is zero for all the physical quantities.
Remarks.

It's possible to have steady compressible flow, governed by the continuity equations with $\partial \rho / \partial t = 0$ (steady condition), namely
$$0 = \underbrace{\dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}}_{=0} + \nabla \cdot (\rho \mathbf{u} ) = \rho \nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} + \mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla  \rho$$

Constant and uniform density $\rho(\mathbf{r}, t) = \overline{\rho}$ implies incompressible flow $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}$, since all the derivatives of the density fields are equal to zero,
$$0 = \underbrace{\dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}}_{=0} + \mathbf{u} \cdot \underbrace{\nabla \rho}_{=0} + \rho \nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} \qquad \rightarrow \qquad \nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} = 0 \ ,$$
but the opposite claim is not true, i.e. incompressible flow assumption alone doesn't imply either constant or uniform density field.



Thank you very much for your time and answer. So overall, to arrive to $\nabla \cdot \vec{v} = 0$ we need to assume both steady state flow ($\partial \rho/ \partial t = 0$) and incompressibility ($\nabla \rho = 0$) correct? Those are the steps I had taken, same as your response, but was thrown off because the slides only stated "incompressibility" and wanted to make sure whether I had misunderstood or the slides had an error.

NO! Incompressibility is either $\frac{D \rho}{Dt} = 0$ or, equivalently $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} = 0$, while the condition $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = 0$ tells you that the density field is a steady field (that may be non-uniform in space, that may be in a compressible fluid).

So the definition that my slide had given me for incompressibility is incorrect, and the correct form is $\partial \rho/\partial t = -(\vec{v} \cdot \nabla)\rho$ ? Just making sure I understood you before marking the question as solved !

They're equivalent: $\nabla \cdot 0$ implies $D \rho /D t = 0$ (or the equivalent expression you wrote in the last comment $\partial \rho / \partial t = - \mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla \rho$), if continuity equation $\partial \rho / \partial t + \nabla \cdot (\rho \mathbf{u}) = 0$: you just need to correctly manipulated the terms of the equations.
